# How to update table ID-s based what is in other table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using version 11.2 Oracle database. I need to update table DOCUMENT_SHARING document_id's based what's in other table, the correct ID should be selected by other unique identifier. One document may have more than one sharing, or maybe not at all. How to do it? I'm stuck.

Here are the table examples:

```
DOCUMENT
id  |   text    |   doc_id
--------------------------
6   |   foo1    |   1021
120 |   foo2    |   1123
123 |   foo3    |   1429
121 |   foo4    |   1527
998 |   foo5    |   1722
542 |   foo6    |   1923

DOCUMENT_SHARING
document_id |   shared_to   |   doc_id
--------------------------------------
            |   human1      |   1021
            |   human2      |   1123
            |   human3      |   1429
            |   human4      |   1527
            |   human5      |   1722
            |   human6      |   1923
```

I want to update table DOCUMENT_SHARING document_id so that the result would be like this:

```
DOCUMENT_SHARING
document_id |   shared_to   |   doc_id
--------------------------------------
6           |   human1      |   1021
120         |   human2      |   1123
123         |   human3      |   1429
121         |   human4      |   1527
998         |   human5      |   1722
542         |   human6      |   1923
```

I have tried following:

```
UPDATE DOCUMENT_SHARING DS SET DS.document_id = (SELECT D.ID FROM DOCUMENT D WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' AND D.doc_id IS NOT NULL AND D.doc_id = DS.doc_id) where DS.doc_id IS NOT NULL;
```

But I get error:

> Error report:
>       SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update   ("SCHEMA"."DOCUMENT_SHARING"."DOCUMENT_ID") to NULL
>       01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"

query "descr DOCUMENT_SHARING"

```
Name             Null     Type           
---------------- -------- -------------- 
DOCUMENT_ID      NOT NULL NUMBER(12)     
USER_CODE        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)       
DOC_ID                    NUMBER(12)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Update DOCUMENT_SHARING DS
set document_id = (
  Select D.id 
  from  DOCUMENT
  where DS.doc_id = D.doc_id)
```

I think that wher you say:

```
UPDATE DOCUMENT_SHARING DS 
SET DS.document_id = 
  (SELECT D.ID FROM DOCUMENT D 
   WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' 
   AND D.doc_id IS NOT NULL AND DS.doc_id = D.doc_id) 
where DS.doc_id IS NOT NULL;
```

You want to say:

```
UPDATE DOCUMENT_SHARING DS 
SET DS.document_id = 
  (SELECT D.ID FROM DOCUMENT D 
   WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' 
   AND D.doc_id IS NOT NULL AND DS.doc_id = D.doc_id) 
where exists
  (SELECT D.ID FROM DOCUMENT D 
   WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' 
   AND D.doc_id IS NOT NULL AND DS.doc_id = D.doc_id);
```

Comment: note: you can use alias for tables in your convenience, but in this case they are not ambiguity.

Comment: I dont understand, you're matching doc_id and document_id, but I should match using both table doc_id columns.

Comment: Sorry @Marko, my mistake! I rewrite sentence, now with mandatory aliases.

Comment: Please look my question, I added some information and query I ran, do you have any ideas why it wont work?

Comment: Please, post a 'descr DOCUMENT_SHARING'. And split sentences in several lines.

Comment: Tried your last update. Result: Error starting at line 14 in command:
UPDATE DOCUMENT_SHARING DS SET DS.document_id = (SELECT D.ID FROM DOCUMENT D WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' AND D.doc_id IS NOT NULL AND DS.doc_id = D.doc_id) where exists (SELECT D.ID FROM DOCUMENT D WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' AND D.doc_id IS NOT NULL AND DS.doc_id = D.doc_id)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: BTW forgot to told, that one document may have more than one sharing, or may be that not at all.

Comment: Then, replace selec d.id be select max(d.id) for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DOCUMENT_SHARING ds
   SET ds.document_id = (SELECT MAX(d.id)
                           FROM DOCUMENT d
                          WHERE d.remote_application = 'DMS'
                            AND d.doc_id = ds.doc_id);
 WHERE ds.doc_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Not working:

Error starting at line 3 in command:
UPDATE DOCUMENT_SHARING ds
SET ds.document_id = (SELECT d.id FROM DOCUMENT d WHERE d.doc_id = ds.doc_id)
Error at Command Line:4 Column:56
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "D"."DOC_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: @Marko I guess I made a typo and forgot to alias the `DOCUMENT` table as `d` ... I edited my answer to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

The `DOCUMENT.ID` null values are causing the trouble. Try this one:

```
UPDATE 
  ( SELECT DS.document_id, D.id
    FROM DOCUMENT_SHARING DS
      JOIN DOCUMENT D 
        ON DS.doc_id = D.doc_id
    WHERE D.remote_application = 'DMS' 
  ) tmp
SET tmp.document_id = tmp.id 
WHERE tmp.id IS NOT NULL ;
```